# How to connect to a folder with credentials in remote server

Tags: c#-4.0

i tried to copy files from specific library in my PC to a library in a remote server,
my question is what i need to use in order to make the connection? which command?
is it should be something like sql connection?

Comment: i solved it using impersonation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used impersonation in order to solved this issue

```
new Impersonator(usr_name_source, domain_source, password_source)
```